# JsonTemplateLayout not providing file name, line number

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I am using the JsonTemplateLayout defined [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/json-template-layout.html) in my project using log4j2. I have the JSON printing out to console and file. However, the JSON log does not contain the file name or line number, despite being in the layout. Is there something missing from the example?

custom format:

```
{
  "mdc": {
    "$resolver": "mdc"
  },
  "exception": {
    "exception_class": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "className"
    },
    "exception_message": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "message"
    },
    "stacktrace": {
      "$resolver": "exception",
      "field": "stackTrace",
      "stackTrace": {
        "stringified": true
      }
    }
  },
  "line_number": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "lineNumber"
  },
  "class": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "className"
  },
  "@version": 1,
  "source_host": "${hostName}",
  "message": {
    "$resolver": "message",
    "stringified": true
  },
  "thread_name": {
    "$resolver": "thread",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "@timestamp": {
    "$resolver": "timestamp"
  },
  "level": {
    "$resolver": "level",
    "field": "name"
  },
  "file": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "fileName"
  },
  "method": {
    "$resolver": "source",
    "field": "methodName"
  },
  "logger_name": {
    "$resolver": "logger",
    "field": "name"
  }
}
```

log4j2.properties:

```
appender.console.json.type = JsonTemplateLayout
appender.console.json.eventTemplateUri = classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to enable locationInfo for the file name / line number stuff to be gathered, e.g.

`appender.console.json.locationInfoEnabled=true`

note that this will have a performance impact.

Comment: The performance impact can be eliminated using the newest tool from Apache Logging Services: [`log4j-transform-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-transform/tree/main/log4j-transform-maven-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure If you want to print the class name, if that can solve your problem you can do it using.

```
 "class": {
    "$resolver": "logger",
    "field": "name"
  }
```

Comment: That's not what the OP was asking for, but it is a valid alternative to enabling the computationally expensive location info.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add this configuration in your log4j config file:

```
appender.console.layout.locationInfoEnabled = true
```